# Restarting a script after X interval of time

Tags: amazon-ec2, python, automation

Not sure I am making sense or not: I run a script on multiple AWS instances under a screen session. The scripts are Python-based and stopped working after a while due to network issue of Amazon Arora and EC2 instance. I logonto machine and get into screen session by doing `screen -d -r <screen_name>`, halt the script and re-run.

Is there a way I can automate it? that is,re-run the script? I have no issue if that other script kill existing screen and then start again

Answer (score 0):

Your subject asks about restarting a script after a set amount of time. If that's the exact scenario, then use `cron` to invoke `python` to run your scripts. My suggestion is to crack open a shell, type `man cron` and enjoy the wonders that unfold before you.

If you want to track if a process is running, and if not, start it up again, you have a few options, but most likely want to write it as a service and use the host operating systems init system to launch it, and then a tool like Monit, upstart, or systemd to make sure it's running and restart it if not.

I'd say you just booked out the remainder of the year with a reading plan. =)

Comment: my question was, how to automate `screen` commands?

Comment: @Volatil3 You don't. You use the tools intended for the job. Which are things like init systems, services, and/or cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a proper init script that runs your script under the terminal multiplexer, restarting the script if it fails. Then, when needed, you can attach to the running `screen` or `tmux` session and monitor your script.

In my case, I have several systemd units that run golang programs on a console under `tmux` and delegate the lifecycle of these golang programs (launch, restart on fail, stop on shutdown, etc) to the "official" init system of your OS.

I used the example in this question as starting point: https://askubuntu.com/questions/802189/how-to-run-tmux-screen-with-systemd-230